# Can I remove a plugin if the user is viewing from a mobile device?

Tags: css, wordpress, html, conditional-statements

I would like to remove a Video Player ( which could be as simple as #video{display:none;} ) if the user is viewing from a mobile device.

My platform is wordpress. Is there a wordpress shortcut, or a way to do this in HTML5/CSS? If not, is there a way to write a simple conditional into Wordpress?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to do this in javascript/CSS. Hard to say which method would suit you best, but based on current best practices I would not sniff the user-agent as suggested, but create a 'responsive' section in your `style.css` which will only be triggered for mobile devices.

```
@media (max-device-width: 480px) {
    #video {
        display: none; 
    }
}
```

Works in all mobile browsers. You can tweak the device-width to your need.

More information about this technique, which is called Responsive Web Design: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/01/12/guidelines-for-responsive-web-design/

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way would to be to use some Javascript to find out what browser is accessing the page and then take some action based off of that.

Info on discovering browser can be found here
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_browser.asp

From there I'd think you'd have 2 options

1. Redirect them to a mobile version of the page using javascript
2. Use javascript to edit the internal html of the element to remove the video stuff

No idea if this is relevant to wordpress or not but this is how I know how to do it.

Comment: Obligatory http://w3fools.com/ link. Browser detection is also a bad idea for lots of reasons: it ends up being imprecise, unscalable and inaccurate. Feature detection should be used instead.

Comment: Better practice is to link to the MDN docs for JavaScript in future: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript